# "Sick" or "ill"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

If I'm not healthy, am I *sick* or am I *ill*?

Are these interchangeable, or do they merely overlap?

Comment: There might be some old, technical difference, but, nowadays, they're used synonymously, at least where I grew up. It'll be interesting if a distinction still exists anywhere...

Comment: Necessary reference for the modern usage of [sick](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAkX1giNels) ;-)

Comment: Here's a simple and logic explanation. The origin of sick is from the old Germanic verb: siech which means to have a disease. It was used in Middle High German and refers to people who had leprosy. These people were sent to a: Siechenhaus the resemblance of which can still be found today in the Dutch word for hospital: ziekenhuis....so actually sick would then mean siech = have a disease....whereas hospital simply means a house for strangers. Similar words are: host, hospitable, hostel, hotel and many more...here we have the Latin origin in contrast to the word sick which has Germanic roots.

Comment: Very, very few pairs of words are totally interchangeable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're generally used synonymously these days, though there was originally a distinction in meaning. "Ill" generically referred to being unwell, whereas "sick" referred to vomiting — this still persists to some degree.

In modern times there has been (and still is to a degree) a distinction between upper-class and non-upper-class usage in British English. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English) for example. The upper-class usage, unsurprisingly, seems to preserve the more traditional meanings of the two words.

```
U                         Non-U
Ill (in bed)              Sick (in bed)  
I was sick on the boat.   I was ill on the boat.
```

Finally, if you're curious you can take a look at the etymologies of [*sick*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sick) and [*ill*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ill). The latter originally only meant "morally evil", curiously enough. This is going back to the high Middle Ages, however. Meanings have been are still in constant flux.

Comment: Yes, that also explains usages like *ill-formed* or *ill-advised*.

Comment: @Tomalak: Indeed, those terms inherit from the older definition.

Comment: Surprisingly, *ill* is not etymologically related to *evil*, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, though they have been synonymous from the 12th century.

Comment: @Cerberus: I wasn't implying they were etymologically related, but they have meant the same thing for a long time. I know of no earlier meaning of the word. (If there is one, it's pretty irrelevant anyway.)

Comment: @Noldorin: I didn't think you were implying anything like that! I just added it as an interesting fact (I was wondering myself and looked it up).

Comment: Oh ok, fair enough. :)

Comment: @Noldorin Your assertion that the two are synonymous is only correct for North American English: Brits use sick as a synonym for "vomit", both the noun and the verb.

Comment: @msanford: If you reread my first paragraph I actually mention that. :) Given that I *am* a Brit, I can verify that.

Answer (score 8):

Normally you feel sick when you are ill.

And *to be sick* often is a synonym to throwing up.

Update: Both words can mean great or wild in recent (hip-hop) slang.

*That DJ has some sick skills*

Comment: It's not just hip-hop slang; that meaning of the word has entered wider American youth culture, and even extended internationally.

Comment: Hence the (hip-hop) in brackets

Comment: I'm not sure it's any more "normal" to *feel sick when you're ill* than it is to *feel ill when you're sick*.

Comment: To add to FFs comment, if "sick" means "feeling like I am going to throw up" I do not always feel sick when I am ill.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that *sick* has lately taken on some new freight: in current slang usages it is replacing *awesome* as the clichéd announcement of approval.

> That is just sick!

or

> That is so sick!

are not used to mean unwell or ill. And while you may not have any trouble distinguishing the meanings when applied via the demonstrative pronoun *that*, the word is also being applied to personal pronouns as well:

> He's so sick!

can mean the speaker is commenting about some outstanding qualities the subject has. Really.

Comment: This is true, but most likely not what the questioner is getting at...

Comment: ...As a teenager, I think that this is pretty old. I mostly just read "sick" used like that in old YA books from the nineties/ early 2000's...Could be regional, though. It seems like slang varies more than anything else does regionally.

Comment: @Noldorin: No, it's not what he's getting at, but it is germane to the discussion.

Comment: @kitukwfyer: I hear it all the time in video gaming and at the poker tables.

Comment: I wonder how the other guys missed this particular connotation of the word

Comment: @Robusto: I'll give you that. It's an interesting side-point. :)

Comment: [Wow. Sick answer.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21852/2637) I knew I'd seen that usage somewhere here on ELU.